# jetty 7 & 8 and Enabling JMX for Maven

Tags: maven, jetty, jmx, maven-jetty-plugin

What is the way of enabling jmx at jetty 7 for maven. I set `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` but still could not be successful. Should I include another dependency for jetty maven plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware of using Cygwin can cause such kind of problems. My problem was because of Cygwin. In order to solve my problem I started JConsole or JVisualvm by Cygwin too...